# Create a native filter in Gmail using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api

I want to make a filter that is native to gmail for certain set of parameters.

Basically I use the google alias function a lot (the + sign after your email). I want to automate the process of creating a filter that reads the "To" line then looks for a "+". If the a "+" is found it will make a label of what is after the "+". Then it will create a dedicated/native filter that will: skip the inbox and apply the label of what is after the "+".

I have looked through the gmail scripts and have not found a way to make a native filter. I understand that this functionality might have just been implemented.

```
function getTo() { 
  // Log the To line of up to the first 50 emails in your Inbox 
  var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(); 
  Logger.log(email); 
  var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0, 50); 
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) { 
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages(); 
    for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) {
      Logger.log(messages[j].getTo()||email); 
     } 
   }
}
```

Any help would be great.

Solution:

```
// Creates a filter to put all email from ${toAddress} into
// Gmail label ${labelName}
function createToFilter(toAddress, labelName) {

// Lists all the filters for the user running the script, 'me'
var labels = Gmail.Users.Settings.Filters.list('me')

// Search through the existing filters for ${toAddress}
var label = true
labels.filter.forEach(function(l) {
    if (l.criteria.to === toAddress) {
        label = null
    }
})

// If the filter does exist, return
if (label === null) return
else { 
// Create the new label 
GmailApp.createLabel(labelName)

// Lists all the labels for the user running the script, 'me'
var labelids = Gmail.Users.Labels.list('me')

// Search through the existing labels for ${labelName}
// this operation is still needed to get the label ID 
var labelid = false
labelids.labels.forEach(function(a) {
    if (a.name === labelName) {
        labelid = a
    }
})
Logger.log(labelid);
Logger.log(labelid.id);
// Create a new filter object (really just POD)
var filter = Gmail.newFilter()

// Make the filter activate when the to address is ${toAddress}
filter.criteria = Gmail.newFilterCriteria()
filter.criteria.to = toAddress

// Make the filter remove the label id of ${"INBOX"}
filter.action = Gmail.newFilterAction()
filter.action.removeLabelIds = ["INBOX"];
// Make the filter apply the label id of ${labelName} 
filter.action.addLabelIds = [labelid.id];

// Add the filter to the user's ('me') settings
Gmail.Users.Settings.Filters.create(filter, 'me')
}
```

}

Thanks, Ender

Comment: Do you want it to run through your inbox now? Or as email comes in? What code have you tried so far?

Comment: So i want it to run every so often to look for new emails that have not been filtered yet. The native filter should be running all the time. I found some filter setting in the advanced functions:https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/filters

Comment: I am testing the .getTo. I am trying to eliminate the difference between my email and the email to check. The difference will be the label. Then once i have the label i want i will make the filter. i have not yet tried makeing the filter.

Comment: function getsubject() {
// Log the subject lines of up to the first 50 emails in your Inbox
 var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
   Logger.log(email);
  var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0, 10);
 for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
  var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
   for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) {
   Logger.log(messages[j].getTo()||email);
 }
 }
}

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The functionality seems to exist, but requires enabling the full Gmail API.

For your Apps script, follow the directions at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced to enable Advanced Google Services.
When I first tried using the `Gmail.Users.Settings.Filters.list('me')` call I got an authorization error which gave me a link to enable the Gmail API in the Developer Console which just amounted to flipping a switch.

Once you have this enabled, you can write a script to make filters, like

```js
//
// Creates a filter to put all email from ${toAddress} into
// Gmail label ${labelName}
//
function createToFilter (toAddress, labelName) {

  // Lists all the labels for the user running the script, 'me'
  var labels = Gmail.Users.Labels.list('me')

  // Search through the existing labels for ${labelName}
  var label = null
  labels.labels.forEach(function (l) {
    if (l.name === labelName) {
      label = l
    }
  })

  // If the label doesn't exist, return
  if (label === null) return

  // Create a new filter object (really just POD)
  var filter = Gmail.newFilter()

  // Make the filter activate when the to address is ${toAddress}
  filter.criteria = Gmail.newFilterCriteria()
  filter.criteria.to = toAddress

  // Make the filter apply the label id of ${labelName}
  filter.action = Gmail.newFilterAction()
  filter.action.addLabelIds = [label.id]

  // Add the filter to the user's ('me') settings
  Gmail.Users.Settings.Filters.create(filter, 'me')

}


function main () {
  createToFilter('youruser+foo@gmail.com', 'Aliases/foo')
}
```

I wasn't able to figure out how to create a filter that retroactively labels messages automatically since Google doesn't seem to expose that in their API.

Comment: wow this is super helpful!!!! Thank you very much! I have never gotten this kind of quality help. I would up vote but i don't have the rep.

Comment: I was planning on looking up the all the .to in my inbox comparing them against my email to get just the label part. Then checking to see if a label had been made for it or a filter already. Then generate the filter with the label that is after the "+".  Once there is a filter if you edit it there would be an option to apply it to the entirety of the email. This will have to do if i can not find a way to move them all into the right label at the creation of the label.

Comment: So i have spent some time with the code trying to implement it but i don't really understand what you were doing with the IF statement. I see that you are checking to see if the filter has already been created but i am not sure how? Also all the test i have run have returned null for label so i am not sure if i am doing something wrong. Comments would help this is my first time using java-script and google scripts.

Comment: Are you sure the label exists? You can try running `GmailApp.createLabel(labelName)` before creating the filter to create the label. Also are your permissions all in order? It took me a bit of trial and error to get those working.

Comment: So I have figured out what i wanted to do. I did need to create the label but only after i check the filters to see if there is a filter set up for the specific address. Once i know there is no filter for the address it will make the label and remove the inbox label and apply the label of the email. Permissions were not a problems. It was more understanding this line:  `labels.labels.forEach(function (l)`  after i got a better grasp on objects based stuff i was able to put the code together. Where should i post the code that i have finished for this? As another answer.