# Issue with GetUserLabelByName Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

I'm trying to use "getUserLabelByName" to only retrieve email threads labeled with "MyLabel", but the script is also pulling emails from the "Sales", "Marketing" labels. These emails do not have the "MyLabel" label and I can't figure out why they would be included in the array when I've specifically told App Script to only pull emails with the label "MyLabel".

I added the Logger.log(To); so that I could see which email addresses were being logged. For background, all emails coming to a certain address, for instance info@company.com should be marked with the label "MyLabel", while other emails sent to other email addresses are assigned different labels. So if were are only collecting emails from "MyLabel", there should be no reason to see any other email addresses in the log other than "info@company.com", but there are other email addresses being captured and I can't figure out how to fix the issue.

```
function getEmail() {
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("MyLabel");
  var threads = label.getThreads();
  Logger.log(label);

      //get first message in first thread
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var messages=threads[i].getMessages();
    for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) {
    var message=messages[j];
    var To=message.getTo();
    Logger.log(To);
    Logger.log(message.getFrom());
```

Yes, there is more to this script but this section is the part with the issue.

Comment: You're code seems to look correct - Can you provide more details and maybe share more code? How are you running/triggering the script?

Comment: Right now I'm just running it as is to enumerate what emails it thinks is associated with the "MyLabel". The rest of it is dependent on this piece just pulling the relevant messages and not a bunch of other messages that it needs to sort through. The messages to all the email addresses are from the same sender with the same subject line, but I've set up filters to make sure that they are assigned the appropriate label. I've tripped checked that only the right messages are assigned the "MyLabel" label, but it keeps including other stuff.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40773241/

Comment: not a duplicate.